# Unknown column 'dob' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am getting error Unknown column 'dob' in 'field list'

I know that dob is in my table and have called it many times and in my code the insert is ordered correctly. I am just learning MySQL so I'm completely lost

```
    insert into users (userid, firstname, username,dob) 
    values ('gg', 'greg', 'greg2', '1980-01-01');
```

here is the table I am trying to insert it into.

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `userid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `middleName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `password` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `occupationId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `userStatusId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `userTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
      UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
      KEY `userStatusId` (`userStatusId`),
      KEY `userTypeId` (`userTypeId`),
      KEY `occupationId` (`occupationId`),
      KEY `lastname` (`lastname`),
      CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userStatusId`) REFERENCES `userStatus` (`userStatusId`),
      CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userTypeId`) REFERENCES `userType` (`userTypeId`),
      CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`occupationId`) REFERENCES `occupation` (`occupationId`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am doing all my work in Sequel Pro

```
    insert into users (userid, firstname, username, dob) 
    values ('gg', 'greg', 'greg2', '1980-01-01');
```

i tried it this was as well and get the same error, then i tried it like this

```
   insert into users (userid,firstname,username,dob) 
   values ('gg','greg','greg2','1980-01-01');
```

here is the code I ran before my insert

```
    delimiter $$

    create trigger usersInsert
    before insert on users
    for each row begin
    set new.created = now();
    set new.age = floor(datediff(now(),dob)/365);
    end $$

    delimiter ;
```

I was trying to see if my trigger was working so I inserted a new user into the user table to make sure it was working properly

Comment: my only thought is you're not connecting to the database/table you think you are.  If you know it to be in the table, are you sure you're connecting to the database which contains that table and field?

Comment: You need to provide us with more information, such as, more of your php code and metadata for the table.

Comment: May be you are having another database with `users` table without `dob` column and you are connecting to it :D. Please check once for safer side :)

Comment: i just checked and I only have one table called users. This is one table of about 20 in an example database I am using to learn MySQL

Comment: What I think is that there may be a possibility of space before or after the column name 'dob'. Can u please recheck it. @RKBacka

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f36/1 - your query is fine, show us screenshot of what are you doing when get this error

Comment: it wont let me because i dont have enough reputation...

Comment: out of curiosity, if you exclude DOB from the insert does it work?

Answer (score 1):

i found where my error was. it was in my trigger

```
    delimiter $$

    create trigger usersInsert
    before insert on users
    for each row begin
    set new.created = now();
    set new.age = floor(datediff(now(),new.dob)/365);
    end $$

    delimiter ;
```

I wasn't using 'new.dob' when setting a value to dob

Thank You for all of your help!